# VBScript and WMI to Map Drive remotely

Tags: vbscript, wmi, network-drive

I have been playing\googling for VBscript to remotely map a drive for a shared Network folder?

can you do it with wmi or just normal vbscript etc... ?

Comment: Network drives are mapped in a user's context, so in general trying to do this remotely is not useful. Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: So I have a vbscript script to remotely install software which works for everyone but me lol...think its my access level...anyway..

I want to map a drive for a client for them to install a piece of software if i cant do it by remote install? does that make sense ?

Comment: I believe a batch script run via [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) might be more suitable for these requirements.

Comment: Or using the native remote scripting via [WshController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk7bxb0d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)